# Rails: jQuery ajax() is returning all the html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The response I'm getting from the ajax is the entire html instead of the form.serialize(). Why this is happening? How do I get only the form.serialize()?

Also, I tried put json in the dataType but then the response return an error.

Thanks

/test.html.erb

```
<form name="boleto_form" action="" id="boleto-form">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Guilherme Bordignon" required>
  <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" value="03310782018" required>
  <input type="submit" name="buy_button" id="buy-button" value="Comprar">
</form>
```

test.js

```
dados = $('#boleto-form').serialize();

console.log(dados);

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "payments",
    data: dados,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('lol' + response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

});
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :orders do
    get '/payments', to: 'payments#test'
    post '/payments', to: 'payments#test'
  end
```

console

```
lol<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mypg</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="QKESaecu5iy7gzgqYlGpkns5UUPaoIgMVC464a12z2ycjNFn9CbB+HxFTWnbTAU57xa/djbFhKz+ml6wzLpo5Q==" />
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.debug-2ff85327b45ccfcb08b5825f21ab8b6d5ee67197751ab00ed866ea21a87f647c.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/packs/js/application-47b020c259890ae2a580.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
      "https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js">
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p class="notice"></p>
    <p class="alert"></p>

    <form name="boleto_form" action="" id="boleto-form">
    <h2>Dados do comprador</h2>

    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Guilherme Bordignon" required>

  <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" value="03310782018" required>
  <input type="submit" name="buy_button" id="buy-button" value="Comprar">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "response from the Ajax"? You wouldn't get `form.serialize()` *back* from the server, you'd get whatever your action returns. What does your action return? You're not setting a content type in your Ajax request, so (IIRC) it defaults to an encoded form. If your action doesn't get a .json extension and you do nothing else you're probably just sending back the HTML as would be expected.

Comment: your routes are a little strange. You route get and post to the same action. It's unconventional. Show us the payments_controller.rb file so we can see how the form is being handled.